# How to optimize query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, explain, database-indexes

I have a really slow query with an execution time of 2 seconds. I tried to optimize it but I can't find out where the problem is, I optimized the table and added indexes to related tables but it is still slow. The query is this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
p.id
FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN brand b ON p.brand_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN supplier s ON p.supplier_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN category_product cp ON p.id = cp.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_option_value pov ON p.id = pov.product_id
LEFT JOIN media m ON p.id = m.product_id AND m.type = 1
LEFT JOIN shop_product sp ON p.id = sp.product_id AND sp.shop_id = '75'
LEFT JOIN category c ON cp.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY p.master_model;
```

The output of this query is:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| Id | select_type | table | partitions |  type  |   possible_keys    |        key        | key_len |      ref       | rows | filtered |              extra              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | ALL    | master_model       | NULL              | NULL    | NULL           | 4063 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY           | 4       | p.brand_id     |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY           | 4       | p.supplier_id  |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cp    | NULL       | ref    | product_id         | product_id        | 4       | p.id           |    3 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pov   | NULL       | ref    | product_option_id  | product_option_id | 4       | p.id           |    4 |   100.00 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | ref    | product_id,type    | product_id        | 4       | p.id           |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sp    | NULL       | ref    | shop_id,product_id | product_id        | 4       | p.id           |    2 |     2.45 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY           | 4       | cp.category_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

Does someone maybe know of other things that could go wrong.

Comment: If you've already added indexes on JOIN field to related tables, then you could change the order of JOIN. Please try to move up the LEFT JOIN of table *shop_product* to top, then to  *media* and then to the rest tables.

Comment: @Gimby - he did..

Comment: The query makes no sense. According to the GROUP BY, it will return 1 row per value of p.master_model, making all the LEFT JOINs useless if they return more than 1 row each, which is highly likely considering the table structures. If you want to select p.id, why not just use "SELECT p.id" ?... I suspect this is not the real query, in which case no-one can answer the question until you post the query!........

Comment: Also, according to EXPLAIN, MySQL thinks the JOIN will generate  4063*3*4*5*2 = 487,560 rows which isn't a 1 millisecond query...

Comment: Not proper to `SELECT id` but `GROUP BY model` unless those two columns are in a 1:1 relationship.  Are they?

Comment: It matters whether you put `m.type = 1` in the `ON` or `WHERE`.  Which place do you really need it?